# Async ShowDialog

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using async/await to asynchronously load my data from database and during the loading process, I want to popup a loading form, it's just a simple form with running progress bar to indicate that there's a running process. After data has been loaded, the dialog will automatically be closed. How can I achieve that ? Below is my current code:

```
 protected async void LoadData() 
    {
       ProgressForm _progress = new ProgressForm();  
       _progress.ShowDialog()  // not working
       var data = await GetData();          
       _progress.Close();
    }
```

**Updated:**

I managed to get it working by changing the code:

```
 protected async void LoadData() 
        {
           ProgressForm _progress = new ProgressForm();  
           _progress.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(()=>_progress.ShowDialog()));
           var data = await GetData();          
           _progress.Close();
        }
```

Is this the correct way or there's any better ways ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your updated solution has a potential race condition; `GetData` could theoretically complete before the dialog box is ever shown; thus it would remain on screen indefinitely (or, more likely, you would get an `ObjectDisposedException`).

Comment: Do you need the form to be modal?

Answer (score 40):

It's easy to implement with `Task.Yield`, like below (WinForms, no exception handling for simplicity). It's important to understand how the execution flow jumps over to a new nested message loop here (that of the modal dialog) and then goes back to the original message loop (that's what `await progressFormTask` is for):

```
namespace WinFormsApp
{
  internal static class DialogExt
  {
    public static async Task<DialogResult> ShowDialogAsync(this Form @this)
    {
      await Task.Yield();
      if (@this.IsDisposed)
        return DialogResult.Cancel;
      return @this.ShowDialog();
    }
  }

  public partial class MainForm : Form
  {
    public MainForm()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    async Task<int> LoadDataAsync()
    {
      await Task.Delay(2000);
      return 42;
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var progressForm = new Form() { 
        Width = 300, Height = 100, Text = "Please wait... " };

      object data;
      var progressFormTask = progressForm.ShowDialogAsync();
      try 
      {
        data = await LoadDataAsync();
      }
      finally 
      {
        progressForm.Close();
        await progressFormTask;
      }

      // we got the data and the progress dialog is closed here
      MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I should return the favor and offer a modest reward to this brilliant answer of yours. I am still baffled about how you came up with this effective, dead-simple, and totally unintuitive solution!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, thank you, it's nice to have a feedback like this :) I think I just happened to be heavily involved in COM + desktop app development in my early days, so I had a chance to learn a thing or two about how message loops and pumping work under Windows and .NET. It's much less relevant these days, but there are some hidden treasures out there I still keep coming back to, like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cbrumme/apartments-and-pumping-in-the-clr). RIP, Chris Brumme, the author of that blog... :(

Comment: That was a nice reading, thanks! It filled some holes in my knowledge about STAs and MTAs, and I also learned that NAs are a thing (Neutral apartments). :-)

Comment: Looks great! Question though, are you sure you need to check IsDisposed? Does Close dispose of it implicitly? I didn't think so because technically there's still a reference to it when you get to the outer 'await' call (i.e. not the one on Task.Yield), but I could be wrong. Looking at ReferenceSource shows it is sending `WM_CLOSE` so maybe it is.

Comment: One other small suggestion... you may want to change you call to 'Close' to set the DialogResult to dismiss it.  Ok may have semantics if someone is actually awaiting on the result. Granted, the only way they'd get there is if they did like you and manually closed it beforehand, but I think that would make a better case to use `Cancel` over `Ok` for that very reason. (i.e. it was manually closed for a different/whatever reason, so cancel any results.)

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe, I think your suggestions make sense, I didn't test all code paths for this snippet at that time. These days, I don't  do much of WinForms/WPF development, but I was to touch this code, I'd probably change it to throw an exception if `IsDisposed` is `true`. I'd still check it, because in theory the form might get closed before the async code flow continues after `Task.Yield()`.

Comment: @noseratio can we use the same for another `ShowDialog()` instead of return data method? like an await for ShowDialog complete.

Comment: @Thrainder not sure I understand the question, could you elaborate?

Comment: @noseratio I added a question by using an example using your code here. If this makes sense to you then please mark as up.   [Click here for MyQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68140392/continue-code-execution-after-calling-showdialog)

Comment: @noseratio what if `LoadDataAsync` contains smth like `Thread.Sleep(5000)` or another hard computation work at the beginning ? will dialog be shown ?

Comment: @isxaker you'd need to wrap anything computational with `Task.Run`, otherwise it will most likely block the message loop.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pattern that uses Task.ContinueWith and should avoid any race condition with your use of the modal ProgressForm:

```
protected async void LoadDataAsync()
{
    var progressForm = new ProgressForm();

    // 'await' long-running method by wrapping inside Task.Run
    await Task.Run(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Display dialog modally
        // Use BeginInvoke here to avoid blocking
        //   and illegal cross threading exception
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {   
            progressForm.ShowDialog();
        }));
        
        // Begin long-running method here
        LoadData();
    })).ContinueWith(new Action<Task>(task => 
    {
        // Close modal dialog
        // No need to use BeginInvoke here
        //   because ContinueWith was called with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        progressForm.Close();
    }), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ShowDialog()` is a blocking call; execution will not advance to the `await` statement until the dialog box is closed by the user. Use `Show()` instead. Unfortunately, your dialog box will not be modal, but it will correctly track the progress of the asynchronous operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reasons I have to use ShowDialog() . Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Always call `ShowDialog()`, `LoadDataAsync` and `Close()` in order to avoid `IsDisposed` as in @noseratio 's answer. So use `Task.Yield()` to delay `LoadDataAsync()` and not `ShowDialog()`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    async Task<int> LoadDataAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Load");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        return 42;
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progressForm = new Form()
        {
            Width = 300,
            Height = 100,
            Text = "Please wait... "
        };

        async Task<int> work()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Yield();
                return await LoadDataAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Close");
                progressForm.Close();
            }
        }
        var task = work();
        Console.WriteLine("ShowDialog");
        progressForm.ShowDialog();
        object data = await task;

        // we got the data and the progress dialog is closed here
        Console.WriteLine("MessageBox");
        MessageBox.Show(data.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try the following:

```
protected async void LoadData()
{
    ProgressForm _progress = new ProgressForm();
    var loadDataTask = GetData();
    loadDataTask.ContinueWith(a =>
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            _progress.Close();
        }));
    _progress.ShowDialog();
}
```