# Show MessageBox but continue async execution

Tags: .net, winforms, async-await

In a WinForms project I have an algorithm running that continually computes data and updates the UI. It looks like this:

```
async Task BackgroundWorkAsync() {
    while (true) {
        var result = await Compute();
        UpdateUI(result);
    }
}
```

Sometimes, depending on what `result` contains I want to show a `MessageBox` but continue running the algorithm immediately. The following does not work because it blocks further processing until the `MessageBox` is dismissed:

```
while (true) {
    var result = await Compute();
    UpdateUI(result);
    if (...) MessageBox.Show(...); //new code
}
```

How can I make the `MessageBox.Show` call non-blocking?

(Yes, this means that multiple message boxes might pop up at the same time. That's OK.)

Comment: It could be annoying for the user but you can create a `Form` and `Show` it to the user.

Comment: Can `BackgroundWorkAsync`/`Compute` run on a background thread?

Comment: `BackgroundWorkAsync` is started in the Load event and runs on the UI thread. What `Compute` does internally should not matter I think. There might be a UI dependency in it.

Comment: I recently answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33411037/1768303

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the code is running at WinForms UI thread, you can use either [Control.BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) if this code is inside a `Form` or `Control`, or the more general [SynchronizationContext.Post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
if (...)
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(...)));
```

or

```
if (...)
    SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ => MessageBox.Show(...), null);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while (true) {
    var result = await Compute();
    UpdateUI(result);
    if (...) Task.Run(() => { MessageBox.Show(...); });
}
```

That should suffice if you don't care about which button a user presses in the popup.

Comment: This runs the message box on a separate thread which makes it non-modal and causes multiple message loops.

Comment: He-he, sorry for necroposting, it's been a while since I visited SO... Anyway: you wanted the message box to become non-blocking, wanted to receive multiple of them - you get it. Why then require now for them to be modal and reside within the main message loop?