# Which of these two methods is the correct one for running a CPU-intense long-running task in a WPF desktop app?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, c#-9.0

In regards to async operations, I understand it's bad practice to use `Task.Run` in your implementation if you are exposing your code in a library to be consumed elsewhere as you should leave such decisions to the caller of your library. That information can be found in the 'duplicate' questions here. ***But that is not what I am asking.*** I am seeking clarification for our own code which is in a WPF desktop app and will never be exposed as a library for others to consume.

Additionally, our task takes 1-2 minutes of intense CPU-processing if that makes any difference.

My question is in our particular case, does it make sense to use a background thread to make our non-async function async, or do we simply make our function async, then call it with await?

Also, the long-running function doesn't do any async/await stuff itself. It's purely a linear, CPU-intensive task, and I don't care where it's run, only that its return value (and the progress) are reported back to the main UI.

That is what I'm seeking clarification on.

I'm using .NET 5.0 with C#9 in a WPF desktop app directly (i.e. this code is not in a library to be shared with others) if it matters.

Here's some (updated for clarity!) sample code illustrating this...

```cs
public static void Main() {

    // Local function to start the import
    // Note: I read I should be using `async void` and not 'async Task' here since
    // this is a top-level async statement and I understand you need this for proper
    // exception handling. Is that correct?
    async void startImport(){

        Debug.WriteLine($"Import starting... IsBackground: " +
            $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");

        var progress = new Progress<string>(message =>
            Debug.WriteLine($"Progress Update: {message}"));
            
        // Toggle the comments on these lines and the line defining
        // CPUIntenseSequentialImport to try it with and without Task.Run() 
        var result = await Task.Run(() => CPUIntenseSequentialImport(progress));
        //var result = await CPUIntenseSequentialImport(progress);

        Debug.WriteLine($"Finished! The result is {result} - IsBackground: " +
            $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");
    }

    startImport();

    Debug.WriteLine($"Import started... IsBackground: " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");
}

// Can you just mark this as async, then use await on it and not need Task.Run(),
// or because it's a long-running task, should you NOT mark it with async, and
// instead use Task.Start() so it gets its own thread from the pool?
static public int CPUIntenseSequentialImport(IProgress<string> progress) {
//static async public Task<int> CPUIntenseSequentialImport(IProgress<string> progress) {

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    progress.Report($"First part of import done - IsBackground: " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    progress.Report($"Next part of import done - IsBackground: " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    progress.Report($"Final part of import done - IsBackground: " +
        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground}");

    return 44;
}
```

When run as-is, you get this (Note the updates are ***not*** reporting from a background thread)...

```
Import starting... IsBackground: False
Import started... IsBackground: False
Progress Update: First part of import done - IsBackground: False
Progress Update: Next part of import done - IsBackground: False
Progress Update: Final part of import done - IsBackground: False
Finished! The result is 44 - IsBackground: False
```

...but when you swap the commented/uncommented lines, you get this (Note the updates ***are*** reporting from a background thread)...

```
Import starting... IsBackground: False
Import started... IsBackground: False
Progress Update: First part of import done - IsBackground: True
Progress Update: Next part of import done - IsBackground: True
Progress Update: Final part of import done - IsBackground: True
Finished! The result is 44 - IsBackground: False
```

Comment: Try await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait( false );

Comment: `Task.Run`, by default, will schedule the work to be done by a Thread Pool thread - this is obviously not needed *always*. You use `Task.Run` when you have to - recommended reading https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: Not following what you're saying.  As I said in my question, I'm trying to understand the difference between using Task.Run vs not in the commented code. The rest is just illustrative.

Comment: *"our task takes 1-2 minutes of intense processing"* <== this is not simulated well by your example. Generally we use `await Task.Delay(1000)` to simulate [I/O-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean) work, and `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to simulate CPU-bound work. What you describe as "intense processing" probably belongs to the second category, but it would be better to clarify it. You should also clarify what type of app you have in mind. What makes lots of sense for a GUI application may make no sense for an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Good point!  Yeah, our Long-running task does *not* do any internal async/await so you're right... my using await `Task.Delay()` was confusing things.  I've updated the code and question to better illustrate what I'm after/asking about.

Comment: There is not much to add since Stephen already gave all the right answers to your question. But you may still want to read [my arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38739403/await-task-run-vs-await-c-sharp/58306020#58306020) about why it's a good idea to use `Task.Run` in the event handlers of your WPF application.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a lot to unpack here, so I'll answer as best I can as I go along.

> I understand it's bad practice to use Task.Start in your implementation if...

It's actually [bad to use `Task.Start` *in any code at all*](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/02/a-tour-of-task-part-8-starting.html). There is one extremely obscure exception to that rule, but in general `Task.Start` just shouldn't be used at all. `Task.Run` is what you should be using to push work to a thread pool thread.

> I am seeking clarification for our own code which is in a WPF desktop app and will never be exposed as a library for others to consume.

That is valuable information. At the end of the day, your own code is your own code, and even if you use things like `Task.Start`, that's up to you. On the other hand, good practices become good practices because people have discovered that they make code more maintainable. (At least, that's the theory I'm sticking with - cargo cults notwithstanding ;)

Specifically, even though you're not distributing your library on NuGet, your code may benefit from *treating* it kind of like a library. Even if it's not in an actual library (dll) project, the code would probably benefit from being treated as though it were in a separate layer. Separation of concerns and all that - the long-running processing code shouldn't know it's being invoked from a UI thread (and, given unit tests, it might *not* be).

> does it make sense to use a background thread to make our non-async function async, or do we simply make our function async, then call it with await? Also, the long-running function doesn't do any async/await stuff itself.

I would say keep it synchronous, then. The only reason you would make it `async` is to unblock the UI thread. But this is the long-running processing code; why should it even know that there *is* a UI thread? To quote [myself](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html):

> Back up to the original problem for a moment. What is the problem? The UI thread is blocked. How did we solve it? By changing the service. Who needs the asynchronous API? Only the UI thread. Sounds like we just seriously violated the “Separation of Concerns” principle.
>
> The key here is that the solution does not belong in the service. It belongs in the UI layer itself. Let the UI layer solve its own problems and leave the service out of it.

On to the code.

> public static void Main()

This is the first problem. Console apps behave quite differently than WPF apps when it comes to `async` because of [the way `await` interacts with the `SynchronizationContext`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). Since your actual app is a WPF app, it's far better to experiment with a sample WPF app than a sample Console app.

> I read I should be using `async void` and not 'async Task' here since this is a top-level async statement and I understand you need this for proper exception handling. Is that correct?

`async void` is used for event handlers. In all other cases, [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). It's not appropriate in a Console app, although it could be used in a WPF app.

> Can you just mark this as async, then use await on it and not need Task.Run()

No. `async` does not start a new thread. When you compile this code, the compiler itself will give you a warning that the method will run synchronously.

> should you NOT mark it with async, and instead use Task.Start() so it gets its own thread from the pool?

This is the best solution. Keep the synchronous method synchronous, and call it using `Task.Run`.

> When run as-is, you get this (Note the updates are not reporting from a background thread)...

Yes, because everything is actually run synchronously. There's nothing asynchronous here at all, and if you tried this in a WPF app, your UI thread would freeze up.

> ...but when you swap the commented/uncommented lines, you get this (Note the updates are reporting from a background thread)...

Yes, because this is a Console application. `Progress<T>` captures `SynchronizationContext.Current` in its constructor, and uses that to marshal progress updates. Since this is a Console app, there is no `SynchronizationContext`, and each `IProgress<T>.Report` gets sent to a thread pool thread. Possibly out of order (`Progress<T>` really shouldn't be used in Console apps at all).

If you ran that in a WPF application, then the `Progress<T>` would capture the WPF `SynchronizationContext` and the progress reports would be sent to the UI thread.

Comment: Hi Stephen! Love your articles. First, I was not the one who voted this down. I swear... people do so much sniping up here, it's really annoying. I hope MS's new pages don't have the same problem. Second, I actually meant `Task.Run` not `Task.Start`.  Typo on my part.  Third, I posted this related question here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453171. Part of my learning this tonight. Can you take a peek there too?

Comment: Also, to be clear, this is *not* a console app. This is from an example WPF playground app where I can dynamically launch 'Code playgrounds' from the UI, and the launcher calls the static main methods on my test types.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Side-note: @Stephen, it was actually your article that I learned about `.ConfigureAwait` so again, I'd love to know if I'm using it correctly or not.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe: There's no usage of `ConfigureAwait` here. For WPF apps, `ConfigureAwait` is not usually necessary unless you have a *ton* of continuations.

Comment: it's in the other question I linked to.  Did you get a chance to take a look there?

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe: I did take a look at it. I recommend reading the [Async ShowDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33411037/263693) answer and building one like that for WPF. But study the existing one first to understand how the nested message loops work and how the code moves between them; I believe WPF's modals have the same requirements.