# What is the "this Form @this" method argument

Tags: c#, async-await

When I was searching for a solution related to `async` method calls in C#, This method was  provided as an answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33406939/async-showdialog). I'm curious what is this style of argument to a method. What does it means by `this Form @this`?

```
public static async Task<DialogResult> ShowDialogAsync(this Form @this)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    if (@this.IsDisposed)
        return DialogResult.OK;
    return @this.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: 1st `this` makes `ShowDialogAsync` to be an *extension method*, it allows `MyForm.ShowDialogAsync()` syntax; second `@this` is a method argument of type `Form` (you can change `@this` into `form` if it's more readable for you), but since `this` is a *key word* we have to use `@` prefix

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for the clue `extension method`!